# Macro expanding parameters as strings

Tags: objective-c, macros, c-preprocessor

I am looking to simplify the writing of "glue" code in my app.

My target is having something like:

`MAKE_KEY(keyname)`

expand as

`#define keyname @"keyname"`

Unfortunately, I am pretty sure I can't use #define in a #define.

So, I am targeting to expand:

`MAKE_KEY(keyname)`

as

`keyname @"keyname"`

so that I can write:

`#define MAKE_KEY(USER_ID)`

and get

`#define USER_ID @"USER_ID"`

How should I do that ?

*Show how you want to use the expanded values in order to help solve your issue*

I would like to generate `#define MY_CONST @"MY_CONST"` without typing two times the word MY_CONST (because I have so many of them to process…)
Then, I will use `MY_CONST` anywhere I need it in the code.

I do that because I will have objects like `people` or `cities` or `plants` or `animals`, etc… that won't have a lots of methods, but rather a lot of variables. These objects need to be serializable.

There are two ways to do this:

1. Have a property for each variable and write the corresponding encode with coder method (a real pain)
2. Have all the data entered in a dictionary and then serialize the dictionary in encodewithcoder.

I have chosen solution #2. But I would still like to have the accessors. So, I could design a macro that would write the accessors for me, by fetching the right value in the dictionary.

The common point between all is that the accessor, and the key for the dictionary all share the same name.

Comment: You are still generating a `#define` from a `#define`.  Show how you want to use the expanded values in order to help solve your issue.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks for your reply. I have updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For constants used throughout the app, it's generally considered best to have all *definitions* of the strings (or other objects) within a single implementation file (for example `Constants.m`) and have a header file *declaring* these instances as `extern` (for example in `Constants.h`):

Constants.h:

```
extern NSString * const CONST_STRING_1;
extern NSString * const CONST_STRING_2;
extern NSString * const CONST_STRING_N;
```

Constants.m:

```
#import "Constants.h"

NSString * const CONST_STRING_1 = @"CONST_STRING_1";
NSString * const CONST_STRING_2 = @"CONST_STRING_2";
NSString * const CONST_STRING_N = @"CONST_STRING_N";
```

One way of cutting down on the typing would be with:

Constants.h:

```
#define EXCONST(name) extern NSString * const name
#define CONST(name) NSString * const name = @#name

EXCONST(CONST_STRING_1);
EXCONST(CONST_STRING_2);
EXCONST(CONST_STRING_N);
```

Constants.m:

```
#import "Constants.h"

CONST(CONST_STRING_1);
CONST(CONST_STRING_2);
CONST(CONST_STRING_N);
```

You'd then be able to reference these constant strings using just the name:

```
dict[CONST_STRING_1] = @"Hello";
```

Note: This is untested and errors are therefore possible.